# Is an internet gateway required for internet connectivity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gateway, vpc

Consider following scenario:
There is a VPC with public subnet. It has a default route table. The instances present in the subnet have elastic ip addresses. The route table associated to this subnet has rules that will allow HTTP traffic to and from the instances in the subnet. This is sufficient for the instances in the subnet to hit internet and vice versa.
Then why we need another device called Internet Gateway?
If the route table, Network ACL, Security Group are in place for a subnet, what is that additional thing an Internet Gateway is doing?

Thanks,
Nilesh

Comment: Try removing that Internet Gateway and see what happens. The instance with the elastic IP will no longer have access to the Internet without an Internet Gateway. ALL traffic between your VPC and the Internet goes through the Internet Gateway. That is the purpose of the Internet Gateway.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for reply, it cleared my doubt. So now since we have a default route table for the subnet , a Internet route table and  an internet Gateway, the traffic from internet will first come to internet gateway  and then to the internet Gateway route table and from there to actual destination instance. The default route table will not be used right?

Comment: @Nealesh a subnet can only be associated with one route table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The route table associated to this subnet has rules that will allow HTTP traffic to and from the instances in the subnet. This is sufficient for the instances in the subnet to hit internet and vice versa.

No, that is not sufficient. If you did not have a route to an internet gateway in the route table associated with the subnet, the instances would not be able to talk to the internet (regardless of whether they had a public ip or not).

For connectivity to the internet, you either need an internet gateway or a NAT gateway.